# build simple IR sensor with 220 ohm and 1000 ohm resistors

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, led, ir, proximity

I am brand new to the arduino board and I am trying to build a simple IR proximity sensor. I bought a handful of emitters and detectors from amazon here:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01HGIQ8NG/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HGIQ8NG)

I am about to pull my hair out and shoot my board with a 12 gauge shot gun if I don't figure this out soon. Can someone point me to a good SIMPLE tutorial that uses ONE emitter and ONE detector and ONE LED. All i can find are a bunch of complex circuits with multiple sets of sensors or a buzzer or whatever else and anything that is as simple as that has no information on schematic or code. Can someone please post a tutorial link?

Comment: You will not get good result in an unshielded environment from a simple setup.  To do well, you need either an external lock-in amplified which does synchronous *analog* detection of a pulsed signal, or to take reading with the ADC and implement a lock-in in software.

Answer (score 1):

You could always start out attempting a simple IR detector circuit.

Google Arduino IR detector brings up several tutorials, such as [this one from the Instructables website](http://www.instructables.com/id/ARDUINO-Burglar-Alarm-Using-Infrared-Emitter-Detec/?ALLSTEPS)

You would have to change the buzzer in tutorial for an LED and resistor in series.